# web.xml error in SOAP web service using intellij and Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, soap

I'm trying to develop a SOAP web service application using IntelliJ and Tomcat, but i have the following error in `web.xml`

> cannot resolve class or package

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Tomcat does not comes with any JAX-WS dependencies, so, you have to include it manually. Maybe this is your problem.

Try to add this to the tomcat **lib** folder:
 - jaxb-impl.jar
 - jaxws-api.jar
 - jaxws-rt.jar
 - gmbal-api-only.jar
 - management-api.jar
 - stax-ex.jar
 - streambuffer.jar
 - policy.jar